# Perforce integration with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, perforce, perforce-integrate

Which Netbeans plugin for Perforce-Netbeans integration is the most reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PerforceNB](http://kenai.com/projects/perforcenb/pages/Home) seems to be the most actively/recently maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately, the PerforceNB plugin does not play well with P4 streams. Response from Perforce after attempting to connect:
Error login: Client 'xxxxxx' requires an application that can fully support streams.

Answer (score 1):

currently there is this other Netbeans plugin to access perforce server, is placed in this [google code](https://code.google.com/p/netbeans-perforce/downloads/detail?name=org-wonderly-netbeans-perforce-2.2.2.nbm&can=2&q=) repo.

It has support for the version 7.2.1 and I am also using with the version 7.3. Even though there are some features which does not work properly, like the diff and in some situations has problems. For example, in our case the configuration just works using the configuration file (.p4config).

The PerforceNB plugin does not work much well with current versions of Netbeans IDE.